# Will sqlite database be port over to iTunes when iphone app got sync

Tags: iphone, objective-c, itunes

I was wondering whether my app's sqlite database will be transfer over to desktop when user sync the app with iTunes or do I need to do some coding to ensure that it will be transferred?

Please advice. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer the content of your document directory's document folder contents by adding `UIFileSharingEnabled` key to your `info.plist`.

Please check the below image:

[image: UIFileSharingEnabled]

After adding this key to your info.plist, when you sync your iPad with iTunes the documents inside the document folder will be listed in iTunes as shown below:

[image: FileSharingiPhone]

This is a nice tutorial for starting the iTunes filesharing: [**How to integrate iTunes file sharing**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app)

Comment: @kevin.ng: with pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

We not only can backup our files on itunes but also in icloud....

this is how the app data is persisted along the the app updation ,ios upgradation....

Answer (score 0):

As you long you put your data files in standard locations within the app's sandbox and you don't explicitly flag the file as a file that shouldn't be backed up, then the data files will be backed up to iCloud or iTunes (depending on how the user has setup device backups).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your file scheme, you can decide which information is necessary and should be backed up and which one should not because it can be easily recreated.

Look for the **"Where You Should Put Your App’s Files"** section

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2